# Why pdb.set_trace() does not go to next line but goes into interactiveshell.py instead?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am using pdb.set_trace() +n to step through each line of my code.
Most of the times it works. I have a new code now and I have set up the trace before a for loop.
When I click 'n', instead of going into the For loop it goes into some interactiveshell.py file:

```
for item in init_times:
(Pdb) n
> c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipython\core\interactiveshell.py(3329)run_code()
-> sys.excepthook = old_excepthook
```

How do I get out of this and resume debugging my code line by line?
It takes forever to step through this interactiveshell and I have no idea what it is or what I need to debug in this.

This is a snapshot of the code where I have the trace before an If Statement:

```
for item in init_times:
    pdb.set_trace()
    if item[0]=='From Seconds':
        start_0.append(1)
    elif item[0]=='To Seconds':
        end_last.append(1)
if len(start_0)>0 and len(end_last)>0:
    full_range = 1
    print('full range')
elif len(start_0)>0 and not len(end_last)>0:
    begin_range_at_0 = 1
    print('data begins at 0')
elif not len(start_0)>0 and len(end_last)>0:
    end_range_at_end = 1
    print('data ends at last row')
else:
    min_start = int(min(t1_comp_init[0], t1_stat_init[0]))    # min_start variable is used in statistics() and comparisons() when both 
    max_end = int(max(t1_comp_init[0], t2_stat_init[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put `pdb.set_trace()` into a function.
It will work well, just like the code below:

```
def s():
    pdb.set_trace()
    a = "aaa"
    b = "bbb"
    c = "ccc"
    return  a + b + c 

s()
```